# Is there a direct link to the eclipse.jdt.core jar?

Tags: maven, sbt, eclipse-jdt

I've noticed many projects put the org.jdt.core jar in a [lib folder](https://github.com/branaway/japid42/tree/master/lib) because it's not available in a maven repository.
sbt, the build tool I'm using, can pull a dependency straight from a URL. However, I can't find any direct links to the jar on the eclipse downloads page. The closes I can find is a link to the entire [jdt zip](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/org.eclipse.jdt-4.2.1.zip) which includes many jar files. I don't believe sbt can extract a jar from a zip dependency.
Is there a direct link, or some other workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depends whether the version you want is already in a repository or not.

**For org.eclipse.jdt.core:**

The tycho project seems to deploy some versions of `org.eclipse.jdt.core` to central. See:

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tycho/org.eclipse.jdt.core/
```

I found that using [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.eclipse.jdt.core%22). One of those might be good enough for your needs. But they don't seem to have the 'official' binaries, just rebuilds of them.

(Note that there's also a [maven.eclipse.org](http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/index.html#welcome), which might be useful for some artifacts. But if doesn't seem to have anything to suit your particular problem.)

**For the general case:**

In general, though you can't find all the eclipse artifacts in maven repositories. So if you can't find what you want in a maven repo, you'll need to find it in the Eclipse p2 repositories yourself. Let's say you want the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` for Eclipse 3.8.1…

The [Eclipse Project Update Sites](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites) wiki page says the update site for 3.8.x is

```
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8
```

That's actually a 'composite' p2 repository for 3.8, 3.8.1, … So next we need to figure out the name of the 3.8.1 repository. The following fetches a jar file containing `compositeArtifacts.xml`, which lists the child repositories, and greps for `3.8.1`:

```
curl -s http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/compositeArtifacts.jar | \
  gunzip -c | \
  grep '3\.8\.1'
```

The result?

```
<child location='R-3.8.1-201209141540'/>
```

That location is a relative path. It tells us the 3.8.1 repository is at

```
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/R-3.8.1-201209141540/
```

Now to fetch the artifact index for that repository. Again, a single XML file in a jar. But this time, it's not a composite repository, so we just ask for `artifacts.jar`:

```
curl -s http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/R-3.8.1-201209141540/artifacts.jar | \
  gunzip -c | \
  grep org.eclipse.jdt.core[\'\"] | \
  sort -u
```

Result:

```
<artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' id='org.eclipse.jdt.core' version='3.8.2.v20120814-155456'>
```

(I'm not sure why `org.eclipse.jdt.core` in 3.8.1 has a version beginning 3.8.2, but that's the way it is. Let's press on…)

So now we can stitch together the URL according to the `<mappings>` element in the artifacts.xml we just fetched. Add 'plugins/' to the repository path; add the version to the plugin name, and then we can fetch it:

```
curl -Os http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/R-3.8.1-201209141540/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.2.v20120814-155456.jar
```

If you find yourself needing more than just one or two jars, you might look into using [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/), or the [Eclipse p2 Ant tasks](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_repositorytasks.htm&cp=2_0_20_3_3) to resolve the artifacts you need into a lib folder before you run your sbt build.

Comment: Dynamite answer, thanks. The tycho maven repo is good enough for me since it has 3.8.x which I couldn't find, the rest is icing!